# Programmatically creating an EntityManagerFactory gives NullPointerException in wildfly

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, wildfly-10, persistence.xml

When programmatically creating an EntityManagerFactory, it produces a Nullpointer when the persistence.xml contains a node `<mappig-file>`.

I have tested this on Wildfly **wildfly-10.1.0.Final**.
I have tried to update Hibernate `hibernate-core-5.0.10.Final` to `hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final` by adding those jar files and then editing the module.xml to point at the new jars:
[image]

Code example of programmatically creating an EntityManagerFactory:
[image]

XML example of persistence.xml:
[image]

It results in a nullpointer on line 37 ?¿? :S (Last bracket of the constructor.)
[image]

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.__createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:66)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
at nl.********.business.core.em.TenantAwareEntityManagerFactoryBean.createEntityManagerFactory(TenantAwareEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:199)
at nl.********.business.core.em.TenantAwareEntityManagerFactoryBean.addNewDataset(TenantAwareEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:109)
at nl.********.business.core.em.TenantAwareEntityManagerFactoryBean.getEntityManagerForTenant(TenantAwareEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:254)
... 259 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.StandardJpaScanEnvironmentImpl.<init>(StandardJpaScanEnvironmentImpl.java:37)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.populate(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:789)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:215)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:170)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:76)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:181)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:129)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:71)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.__createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:52)
... 291 more
```

Does anybody have a clue why this is happening?
When I remove the  it works. Even when I remove the content of the orm.xml it will give the NullPointerException.
You can see that I have debugged it to that line and NO NullPointerException should occur there, because it's the closing bracket of the Constructor..

The reason that I want to add the orm.xml to the persistence.xml is because I want to add an EntityListener that does not belong to the domain.jar (where the entities life).
The EntityListener contains some business logic.
So if someone knows a workaround to achieve this, that is also welcome, but of course I prefer to just fix the NullPointerException.

---

EDIT: Obviously, these kind of breakpoints are usually the result of different versions. However, we've checked the following places: pom.xml; `.m2` Maven folder; Wildfly deploy folder; Eclipse libraries and Maven libraries; `getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation‌​()` on debug. All these give the exact same result: version `5.2.10.Final.jar`.

If anyone knows any other place to look for a potential different version which might cause this issue, I'd love to know.

Comment: if some line number doesn't coincide with code then you have inconsistent code for what you are running; hence find the right version of the code

Comment: @NeilStockton Yes, I know that. But what is the right version? We checked in the pom; .m2 folder; Wildfly deploy folder; Eclipse; debug message when using `getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()` and all give the same result: version `5.2.10.Final`. If you know another place to check what might be a different version, then I'd love to know. (PS: Currently I'm at home, so I'll have to check tomorrow at work.)

Comment: When anything is released into Maven it should also have a source jar present in Maven central, and that should coincide with the normal jar in your CLASSPATH. If it doesn't then either your CLASSPATH is finding a different jar, or the people releasing that software have put inconsistent versions of jar and source.jar